# Reading RSS feed with simplexml_load_file() outputs nothing

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed

i try to read this rss feed but it always outputs nothing:

```
<?    
$rss=simplexml_load_file('http://www.polizei.bayern.de/mittelfranken/polizei.rss');    
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item)    
{    
   echo "<b><a href=".$item->link.">".$item->title."</a></b><br>";
   echo $item->description."<br><br>";    
}     
?>
```

The script is very popular on the web, so maybe the problem is the feed? Because it's not in the right format or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Please open a new tab in your browser and press F12 key. Check the "network" and "console" tabs and see if there are errors. Update your question with the results of those tabs and any additional information that you can provide and can be usefui for solve this problem.

Comment: Use `$rss->channel->items` in foreach. The `channel` tag has `items`

Comment: @Mauricio Just test the script yourself, F12 doesn't help much.

Comment: @Mohammad: Yes the channel has items too, but they are just links... the really content is below in item-tags.

Comment: But `item` isn't in `channel` tag.

Comment: @WeekendCoder and the "network" tab? you should elaborate a little better what kind of "problems" you're facing.